# How to Disable the value of combobox selected in another combobox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have three comboboxes :

Each combobox have following values to select :

Combobox 1:

1. English
2. French
3. Spanish
4. Italian

Combobox 2:

1. English
2. French
3. Spanish
4. Italian

Combobox 3:

1. English
2. French
3. Spanish
4. Italian

When the values are selected in Combobox 1 let's say English, then this value is to be disabled in Combobox 2 & 3 both. I want to do this in javascript. can any body help. I want to disable this value not to delete it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function selectedLanguage(lang,comboxbox_id){

                console.log(comboxbox_id);

                var langSelected = lang.options[lang.selectedIndex].value;
                console.log(langSelected);

                if(comboxbox_id === 'language1'){

                    if(langSelected === 1){
                        //do nothing
                        document.getElementById('language2').style.disabled = true;

                    }else if(langSelected === 2){

                    }

                }else if(comboxbox_id === 'language2'){
                    if(langSelected === 1){
                         //do nothing   

                    }else if(langSelected === 2){

                    }
                }                
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <select name="language1" id="language1" onchange="selectedLanguage(this,this.id)">

              <option value="1">French</option> 
              <option value="2">English US</option> 
              <option value="3">Greek</option> 
              <option value="4">Swedish</option> 

        </select>


        <select name="language2" id="language2" onchange="selectedLanguage(this,this.id)">

              <option value="1">French</option> 
              <option value="2">English US</option> 
              <option value="3">Greek</option> 
              <option value="4">Swedish</option> 

        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexChar I have edited the Question. Please see what i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$(document).on('change', '.combobox', function() {
    var $otherComboOptions = $('.combobox').not($(this)).find('option'),
        value = this.value;

    $otherComboOptions.each(function() {
        if (value === this.value) {
            this.disabled = true;
        } else {
            this.disabled = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like jQuery, but I don't see that mentioned in the question or tags.

Comment: It could be rewritten in vanilla javascript but I am assuming people use jQuery unless stated otherwise. The question is not very specific.

Comment: I wouldn't go making assumptions, and if you feel that the question isn't specific enough, then you should post a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: guys calm down. don't fight. But until and unless i was trying to use javascript not jquery ...

Comment: No its not working.. please tell me in the same way as in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ocrozmkn/6/